# change reports datasource through sql script in SQL Server reporting services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

i need an sql script that is going to change the datasource of all reports that are inside of some folder, for example http://localhost/Reports/f1

i have 2 datasources(d1 and d2) and 2 folders (f1 and f2) with reports

all the reports from f1 have as datasource d2 and i need to set them to d1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i guess there is no such thing, at least i didn't found it

Comment: If anybody is still interested in the rsScripter. You can find it here.

http://web.archive.org/web/20120830141644/http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62

or

https://sqlserverfinebuild.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Install%20Reporting%20Services%20Scripter

Answer (score 1):

Would the [Reporting Services Scripter](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62) help?

Answer (score 1):

No straight forward answers. But you can achieve if you follow below steps:

1. Download [Reporting Services Scripter](http://www.sqldbatips.com/showarticle.asp?ID=62) and generate the scripts with New Parent folder option checked.
2. Modify the NEWPARENT variable in the .cmd file to your new folder. Make sure you add the "/" if it is from the root folder. For e.g., /NewFolder
3. Open all your *.rss files in notepad++ (or any editor) and globally replace the dsr0.Reference = "/Old_Folder/Old_DataSource" to dsr0.Reference = "/New_Folder/New_DataSource".
4. Execute the .cmd file and that's it.

Thanks to that person who created the rsScripter. Otherwise I would have ended up sitting and modifying all the datasources.